# is there a way to normalize [-3,1] to ${\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}\\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\\ \end{bmatrix}}$ with python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, numpy, normalization

I am learning [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) by following this [MIT course](https://youtu.be/Yw1xmxPH_ps?t=316)

The lecturer is trying to normalize a vector

$${\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}}$$

to

$${\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}\\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\\
\end{bmatrix}}$$

I tried this with Python NumPy

```
np.linalg.norm(v1,ord=2,axis=1,keepdims=True)
```

and got

```
array([[3.],
       [1.]])
```

I would like to get something like this

```
[[-0.9486833 ],
[ 0.31622777]]
```

is there a way with Python (for instance, NumPy) to do the job? any other 3rd party library is also appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already computed that, but you've not bound the output to a variable, also called *name* in python. Try the following snippet:

```
result = np.linalg.norm(v1,ord=2,axis=1,keepdims=True)
print(result)
```

---

Based on the edit, I update the answer. As you may find [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21030391/5120235) to your question, a typical way to find what you need is something like the following function:

```
def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm == 0: 
       return v
    return v / norm
```

Equivalently, there is a function called `normalize` in `sklearn.preprocessing` which can be employed for your task.